# Jquery Splice or Split by '('

Tags: jquery, split, slice

I have values like: "Kurt Cobain (13)". Obviously without the double quotes. I'm looking to fetch the value within the round brackets. The values are in a table in 's.

I've used .each to get ( this ).html to fetch the whole value, then was thinking of using .split("(") rather than slice since the values inside the brackets vary. The key is to start from the back of the value and store everything from the back till the "(".

any ideas anyone?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: User replace method instead of split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
var x = "Kurt Cobain (13)";
x.substring(x.indexOf('(') + 1,x.indexOf(')'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8dnnH/)

Comment: THANKS guys it's superb! mind me ask, the possibility of trimming var x to hold only "Kurt Cobain" since I'm now storing the value 13 in var y. any ideas?

Comment: @hihaho67 So you want to get the name only from that variable right..?

Comment: @hihaho67 Hey that's a kind of interesting one.. ask that as a new one so that you can get more attention over that..!

Comment: Thanks to you I now managed to store the digits in the value, WORKED brilliantly. now need to store just the text in the value so var y would hold "Kurt Cobain" and var x would hold "13".